# How to redirect my content type form after submitting in module

Tags: 7, uri, redirection, forms

How to redirect my content type form after submitting in module.

Code:

```
function message_proposal_form_alter( & $form, & $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == "article-node-form") {
    $form['submit'][] = 'my_callback_function';

  }
}
```

And

```
function my_callback_function($form, $form_state) {
  unset($_GET['destination']);
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/article';
}
```

Comment: You tried and?.. What was the effect? "is not redirected" is pretty vague. Is function called at all? Some kind of PHP error happens? HTTP 500? Any redirection http headers sent or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node Save Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_save_redirect) module.

> This module provides a method of specifying a location to take the user after saving a piece of content.
>   A set of radios buttons are added to the submission vertical tab on the content type edit form.

The available options are:

Default - Default behaviour

Return to Edit page after saving

Return to content overview page (assuming the user has access permissions

Re-redirect to another location. (any valid drupal path)

Or you may try to add submit function to 'Save' button

```
function mymodule_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_node_form_id') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_form_redirect_submit';
  } 
}

function mymodule_node_form_redirect_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/article';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to do using custom module.